# Hibernate AssertionFailure

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

When I try to save a new entity to the database, I have the following error:

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in xxx.nameBean entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

produced at the code

```
 session.save(nameBean)
```

but, "magically" it only appears at Production Server. When I try to reproduce the error at localhost, with the same code and data (using copy of the DB of Production Server, via bak file) it works ok.

What can it be?

EDIT: Adding the code that probably cause the error. The objective of that code is save the bean and update the otherBean in the same transaction, so if something wrong ocurrs make the rollback.

```
public class BeanDao extends ManagedSession {

public Integer save(Bean bean) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = createNewSessionAndTransaction();

        Integer idValoracio = (Integer) session.save(bean);
        doOtherAction(bean);

        commitTransaction(session);

        return idBean;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        if (session != null) {
            rollbackTransaction(session);
        }
        throw re;
    }
}

private void doOtherAction(Bean bean) {
    Integer idOtherBean = bean.getIdOtherBean();
    OtherBeanDao otherBeanDao = new OtherBeanDao();
    OtherBean otherBean = otherBeanDao.findById(idOtherBean);
    .
    .
    .
    otherBeanDao.attachDirty(otherBean)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, it's probably caused by attempt to use a session after it thrown an exception. Make sure your code doesn't swallow any Hibernate exceptions.

Comment: That's interesting. I have added the code because I don't know how to do the two actions in the same transaction correctly. If I put doOtherAction(bean); after  commitTransaction(session); I think that solves the error, but then the actions aren't in the same transaction